# What is the best Neural Network architecture for mapping one input image to two outputs?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, ocr

I have generated a data set using EMNIST that has one character per image or two characters per image.The image is sized at 28x56(hxw)

I basically want to predict the one or two characters in a given image. I am not sure on which architecture to follow to implement this. There are 62 character classes.

ex:-[single character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcqjE.png) [two characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQhiF.png)

For single character y= [23]

For two characters y= [35,11]

I tried the following.

1. I tried implementing this thorough a CTC but I got stuck in a infinite loss that I couldn't fix.
2. Padded the single character ground truths with 62 to note a blank character and trained a CNN with following layers.

print()

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

y_train = sequence.pad_sequences(y_train, padding='post', value = 62)
y_test = sequence.pad_sequences(y_test,padding='post', value = 62)

X_train = X_train/255.0
X_test = X_test/255.0

input_shape = (28, 56, 1)
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=72, kernel_size=(11,11), padding = 'same', activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=144, kernel_size=(7,7) , padding = 'same', activation='relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=144, kernel_size=(3,3) , padding = 'same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(.5))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=2, activation='relu'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
batch_size = 128
steps = math.ceil(X_train.shape[0]/batch_size)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=False,  # set input mean to 0 over the dataset
        samplewise_center=False,  # set each sample mean to 0
        featurewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide inputs by std of the dataset
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,  # divide each input by its std
        zca_whitening=False,  # apply ZCA whitening
        rotation_range=0,  # randomly rotate images in the range (degrees, 0 to 180)
        zoom_range = 0.2, # Randomly zoom image
        width_shift_range=0.2,  # randomly shift images horizontally (fraction of total width)
        height_shift_range=0.1,  # randomly shift images vertically (fraction of total height)
        horizontal_flip=False,  # randomly flip images
        vertical_flip=False)

history = model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train,y_train, batch_size=batch_size),
                              epochs = 6, validation_data = (X_test, y_test),
                              verbose = 1,steps_per_epoch=steps)
```

I was able to reach an accuracy of around 90% for validation set. However when I feed a generated image to see it's prediction it's a few characters off from the correct classification. Is there something wrong in the way I have created the model or pre-processed the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recognized my error. I have tried to tackle the problem using regression method wheres the problem is a classification problem.